# Plot hidden under another plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, charts, candlestick-chart

I am creating a candlestick chart representing stock prices. Once created, I want to add green circle showing where/when I am buying the stock.

```
hold on;
candle(myData.High, myData.Low, myData.Close, myData.Open, '', myData.Date, 'dd/mm/yy');
m = plot(myExecutionTable.BuyDate,myExecutionTable.BuyPrice,'og')
uistack(m)
hold off;
```

The problem is that if myExecutionTable.BuyPrice has a value between the Open and Close, the circle is not showing up. I guess it is hidden under the candlestick. Hence I tried to use uistack but without success. When I change to

```
plot(myExecutionTable.BuyDate,myExecutionTable.BuyPrice+100,'og')
```

the green circle then appears (above the candlestick)

Thanks, 
Serge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to make sure one graphics object is on top of another (and not below), is to plot it *later*.

If for some reason you can't do it this way, you can also manipulate the order of the child objects of the axes:

```
h = get(gca, 'Children');
```

returns a vector of graphics handles. Exchange handles between positions in this vector (higher index means higher on top), and then write it back using

```
set(gca, 'Children', h)
```